# Store non-static method in variable Java

Tags: java

Is there any way to store a class's non-static method in a variable?
I'm guessing that if this is possible it should be marked as `final`.

The C++'s equivalent would be something like:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
    
public:
    void function(int i) {
        
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
        
    }
    
};

typedef void (MyClass:: *func_t)(int);

int main() {
    
    func_t func = &MyClass::function;
    
    MyClass A;
    
    (A.*func)(10);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I wasn't specific enough, I want the object not to be stored within the variable, like in the C++ example. Such that, I can change object but keep the same function.

Comment: `A.*func` doesn't look like valid C++ syntax (but it's been a while since I have seriously programmed C++)

Comment: @knittl the code above compiles, I have no clue if it's been added in a recent version of C++, but to me it seems like an old feature.

Comment: Yes, you can assign a method reference to an instance (non-static) method in a variable; and no, it must not be marked  `final` (example: `ToIntFunction<String> test = String::length;`)

Comment: "_and no, it must not be marked final_" -- To perhaps phrase that better, it may or may not be final.

Comment: @GuillemVS I recommend you research _functional interfaces_, _lambda expressions_ and _method references_ in Java.

Comment: sorry, English is not my first language:  "it can be marked `final`"  - when a reference to an instance method is saved in that way `Class::method`  (instead of `instance::method`), the first argument, when called, is the instance (`this` inside the method - the *hidden* first parameter of every instance method)

Comment: @user16320675 oooh, I wasn't aware that it is possible to store a method ref that way and invoke it with the "hidden" `this` param bound to a specific instance of the class. That's very neat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a compatible SAM type, you could simply assign the method reference:

```
interface VoidIntFunc {
  void call(int i);
}

class MyClass {
    public void function(int i) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final VoidIntFunc func = new MyClass()::function;
        func.call(42);
    }
}
```

Fortunately, Java already defines exactly this SAM type: [`java.util.function.IntConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntConsumer.html):

```
class MyClass {
    public void function(int i) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final IntConsumer func = new MyClass()::function;
        func.accept(42);
    }
}
```

If you want an "unbound" method reference, get the reference of the method from the class and make sure to define the method in your SAM type with the first parameter having the type of the class/instance (this parameter will be the `this` when the method reference is called). Thanks to [user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675) for pointing this out in the comments!

```
class MyClass {
    public void function(int i) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final ToIntFunction func = MyClass::function;
        func.applyAsInt(new MyClass(), 42);
    }
}
```

---

Other options include using Reflection to obtain a `java.lang.reflect.Method` object and invoke it or to look up a `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle`.

Example invoking a `Method` instance:

```
class MyClass {
    public void function(int i) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {
        final Method method = MyClass.class.getMethod("function", int.class);

        final MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        method.invoke(obj, 42);
    }
}
```

The example for method handles is similar, but requires a slightly different API:

```
class MyClass {
    public void function(int i) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) throws Throwable {
        final MethodHandle methodHandle = MethodHandles.publicLookup()
                 .findVirtual(MyClass.class, "function", MethodType.methodType(void.class, int.class));

        final MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        methodHandle.invokeExact(obj, 42);
    }
}
```

Comment: For those wondering, SAM stands for Single Abstract Method. Any interface with a single abstract method is a functional interface and can be a target type for lambda expressions and method references.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Comment: I wasn't specific enough, I want the object not to be stored with the variable, like in the C++ example. Such that, I can change object but keep the same function.

Comment: @GuillemVS please see updated answer. You should be able to achieve your task with Reflection or method handles.

Comment: Using method handles, findVirtual… is quite complex when simply `Class::method` can fit the question.

Comment: @FrédéricLOYER `Class::method` does not meet the requirement of the question that "I can change object but keep the same function", since it requires an instance to create.

Comment: It should be noticed that reflection is the worst way to do this.  It should be the last possible choice.

Comment: @VGR worst way on what dimension? Simplicity of code? Support by old(er) Java versions? Flexibility when it comes to invoking the method?

Comment: @M. Justin. I havn’t written `instance::method` but `Class::method`. No instance involved. Like a part of the answer after an edition.

Comment: Reflection is slow;  it’s much less likely to be optimized by the JIT compiler.  Reflection is error-prone, because we cannot verify correctness of calls at compile-time.  Reflection is harder for developers to follow, making maintenance considerably more difficult.

Answer (score 4):

A method reference from a class is simply named `Class::method`. That's it...

But you have to find a compatible type definition. Using `java.util.function` package, you can use `Consumer`s or `Function`s interfaces. Note that your function type must admit as a first parameter, the object on which the function should apply. (This differs from `instance_of_class::method` where the instance is embedded in the expression).

You may also define your own lambda function signature (an interface with a single method).

Then, you can type:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class A {
    int a;
    void print_a() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        A aa = new A();
        aa.a = 42;
        Consumer<A> method = A::print_a;
        method.accept(aa);
    }
}
```

Note that calling the reference uses the method of the lambda expression (`accept` with `Consumer`s, `apply` with `Function`s, and what ever you have used in a custom lambda interface).